# Will a Bluetooth controller work with an Android app running on BlueStacks?

Tags: bluetooth, bluestacks, game-controllers

My son wants to play the mobile version of [Skylanders Trap Team](https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailsid=com.activision.skylanders.trapteam) on his micro tablet a.k.a. [LG Optimus Exceed 2](https://www.lg.com/us/cell-phones/lg-VS450PP-optimus-exceed-2) with no service. Apparently, it is not compatible with his phone, even though it runs Android KitKat 4.4.2.

I tried some of the free Skylanders Android games on BlueStacks, and they seem to run well. Before I buy the game and [controller pack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MG38CG8), I'd like to hear opinions of whether the Bluetooth controller is likely to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain you can install it in BlueStacks, I purchased the Skylanders Trap Team Android kit myself and have been unable to install the app on any of my non-compatible devices, including BlueStacks. The controller and portal, while recognized by my "smart" devices and my Bluetooth 4.0 PC, fail to pair. It requires the app to be running for the portal and controller to pair.

Since Google Play won't let you download incompatible apps, you have to find the APK file elsewhere. Every time I try to install the APK file in BlueStacks, I get the error message, "download failed because you may not have purchased the app" despite it being a free app.

I can tell you that the Trap Team portal/remote is the same as the Superchargers one, and so work on the Skylanders Superchargers app which is free if you own the Hot Streak car. However, that is only available to Apple devices.

My recommendation is that kit is about $10, and Hot Streak is > $15 that is half the price for Superchargers. Otherwise, if you can manage to get the app to run in BlueStacks and your PC has Bluetooth 4.0 (maybe earlier versions), it should work.